# Releasing file handlers when terminating Qt threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, qt, file-handling

I am developing an application with back end code written in C and using QT for Gui development. For that purpose, I have generated dll which is written in C and contains the back end functions like encrypting a file. I am calling file encryption function in QT thread and updating the current progress in progressing bar dialog.

When cancel button of progress dialog is clicked, I generate a QT signal to tell the thread to terminated. Now problem starts here. When I terminate the thread which runs encryption function in dll, the thread is terminated and encryption also stops but process is not able to delete the incomplete temporary file which was result of encryption.

My understanding is that when encryption function is cancelled, file handlers that my dll has opened have not yet been closed so when when I try to remove temporary file externally, it does not let me delete because my application is hanging on to that file.

My question is that what approach should I take so that my dll releases all file handlers when, thread in QT, which is running it is terminated? Should I send signals like SIGABRT etc to the process itself?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your thread based on an instance of some custom class? Can't you do it in the class destructor then?

Comment: When you say "terminate", do you mean `QThread::terminate()`? Did you read the warning in the docs - _Warning: This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use this function only if absolutely necessary._ They warn exactly about what you encountered.

Comment: I get it but what other techniques can I apply to properly terminate the thread so that my process gives up held resources?

Comment: Simply have a per-thread variable that can be set from other threads that the C library code checks in the loop where it does the encryption. The pointer to that variable will need to be passed to the C function.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that.